# Injector:modulerr in the config (newbie)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the application config as shown below, when i use  method > **function redirectWhenLoggedOut($q, $injector)** i get **Injector:modulerr** error and when commenting that block of function the application runs fine. Help me if i miss anything in this code of config block. I'm new to angularjs hope you will help me out.

```
app.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$authProvider', '$controllerProvider',  '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$ocLazyLoadProvider', 'JS_REQUIRES',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $httpProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $ocLazyLoadProvider, jsRequires) {

app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
app.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
app.filter = $filterProvider.register;
app.factory = $provide.factory;
app.service = $provide.service;
app.constant = $provide.constant;
app.value = $provide.value;

$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    debug: false,
    events: true,
    modules: jsRequires.modules
});

function redirectWhenLoggedOut($q, $injector) {
    return {

        responseError: function(rejection) {

            // Need to use $injector.get to bring in $state or else we get
            // a circular dependency error
            var $state = $injector.get('$state');

            // Instead of checking for a status code of 400 which might be used
            // for other reasons in Laravel, we check for the specific rejection
            // reasons to tell us if we need to redirect to the login state
            var rejectionReasons = ['token_not_provided', 'token_expired', 'token_absent', 'token_invalid'];

            // Loop through each rejection reason and redirect to the login
            // state if one is encountered
            angular.forEach(rejectionReasons, function(value, key) {

                if(rejection.data.error === value) {

                    // If we get a rejection corresponding to one of the reasons
                    // in our array, we know we need to authenticate the user so 
                    // we can remove the current user from local storage
                    localStorage.removeItem('user');

                    // Send the user to the auth state so they can login
                    $state.go('login.signin');
                }
            });
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}

// Setup for the $httpInterceptor
$provide.factory('redirectWhenLoggedOut', redirectWhenLoggedOut);

// Push the new factory onto the $http interceptor array
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('redirectWhenLoggedOut');

$authProvider.loginUrl = 'http://localhost/himalayan-engineering-college/public/api/authenticate';
// APPLICATION ROUTES
// -----------------------------------
// For any unmatched url, redirect to /app/dashboard
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login/signin");
//
// Set up the states
$stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/app.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('modernizr', 'moment', 'angularMoment', 'uiSwitch', 'perfect-scrollbar-plugin', 'perfect_scrollbar', 'toaster', 'ngAside', 'vAccordion', 'sweet-alert', 'chartjs', 'tc.chartjs', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert','satellizer','AuthController'),
        abstract: true
    }).state('app.dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/dashboard.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('satellizer','jquery-sparkline', 'dashboardCtrl','chartsCtrl'),
        title: 'Dashboard',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Dashboard'
        }
    })....//more states
}]);
```

Comment: Can you try correcting the order of dependencies in the function? '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider' are interchanged may be?>

Comment: I have posted it as answer. you may accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try correcting the order of dependencies in the function? '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider' are interchanged.